If $R$ has only a finite number of simple modules up to isomorphism, does it necessarily follow that $R$ is a semi-local ring?
If $R$ is a semi-local ring, then $R$ must have only finite simple modules up to isomorphism. The following paragraph provides a detailed explanation.
Given that $R$ is a semi-local ring, $R/J$ is semisimple, where $J$ denotes the Jacobson radical of $R$. If $S$ is a simple $R$-module, then $S$ is isomorphic to $R/L$ for a certain maximal left ideal $L$. As $J$ represents the intersection of all maximal left ideals in $R$, $L$ must contain $J$. Consequently, there exists a surjective morphism from $R/J$ to $R/L$. Since $R/J$ is semisimple, $R/L$ must be a direct summand of $R/J$. Given that $R/J$ comprises only a finite number of direct summands, it follows that $R$ possesses only a finite number of simple modules up to isomorphism.
Regarding the question:
Is the converse true? If $R$ has only a finite number of simple modules up to isomorphism, does it necessarily follow that $R$ is a semi-local ring?

@RHspqr Please answer in the solutions and not in the comments. Thanks!

There might be much simpler examples, but I found the following example on the DaRT Database of Ring Theory.
It's a bit complicated to define from scratch (it depends on Kolchin's definition of a universal differential field), so I won't give the definition here, but a ring $R$ is described in
Cozzens, J. H., Homological properties of the ring of differential polynomials, Bull. Am. Math. Soc. 76, 75-79 (1970). ZBL0213.04501,
and in Theorem 1.4 it is proved that it has a unique simple right module, and that it is a right $V$-ring, which means that the Jacobson radical of every right module is zero, and hence implies that it can't be semilocal unless it's semisimple, which it's not.

Thank you very much for the detailed explanation and the reference to Cozzens' work on the properties of the ring of differential polynomials. I appreciate the effort you took to provide such a comprehensive answer and the specific citation which will certainly enhance my understanding of this complex topic. This information is very helpful for my studies in ring theory. Thank you again for your assistance and for sharing your expertise!
